# Is there a PEP for Python's EGG format?

Tags: python, setuptools

Since there is a PEP for the Python Wheel format (actually two: [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0427/) and [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0491/)), I am wondering if there is a specification, similar to that of the wheel format, for Python's EGG format.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a PEP for it, but there is [this](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/deprecated/python_eggs.html) from the setuptools documentation.